# Suspicious google tag manager

Tags: plugins, html, google-analytics, virus

I'm trying to integrate some analytics into my site and whilst debugging why mine wasn't working, I found this line being put in the head of my document:

`<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-75655200-4&amp;l=c69d3b65dc6d40db98d2e3ee3cc1fd37"></script>`

Now... It's weird because I've disabled any plugins I had doing google analytics. Additionally, when I look up that account ID, I find references to some company called KyinWebSEO that I've never heard of or done any kind of business with (that exact tag is on the source of their site).

Two main questions here:

- Did I get some kind of virus in one of the plugins I've downloaded? I have plugins related to analytics deactivated so unless one of the other plugins I have is doing that, not sure where it is coming form
- Any advice on finding what is injecting it other than disabling all plugins?

Google the following to see sitewiki links: `google tag manager "UA-75655200-4"`

Comment: Thinking it is a malicious agent/plugin. When I google `wordpress plugin` with that tag, I get top results with `cutestat.com` and https://www.whois.com/whois/cutestat.com shows what seems to be a possibly fake organization. Sketchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I disable `Content Visibility for Divi Builder` then the tag goes away. Seems suspicious... maybe they got hacked or maybe they are bad cookies. Will try to move this to the proper reporting channels. AoD Technologies LLC is the developer.

**Edit: wanted to temper this with a third possibility of tracking the usage of their plugin**

**Edit 2: the developer replied https://wordpress.org/support/topic/injects-suspicious-google-tag-manager-id/ I found a bug but the tracking code is theirs for tracking usage of the plugin. False alarm**